# Coding on those controls, that added from UIBuilder not applied

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

When am adding UIControls from Interface builder, at run time changing some of properties of that controls, so the changes are not getting applied. XCode 4.5.

Anything else, for eh. in settings we have to do something to do this.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean...

Comment: just check reference of these controls..or delete reference and give it once again..